# uploading csv into solr with simpleposttool

Tags: csv, solr

I want to upload my .csv file into my solr core using simpleposttool but there is a problem. My excel creates .csv file with semicolon **;** because of that I'm replacing semicolon **;** with comma **,**. But there are some other comma **,** in my .csv file's data, so when I'm trying to upload .csv file, I'm getting this error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okznX.png)

17 commas separates datas but some datas has commas either. I've been dealing with this for a long time but there is no progress for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [configure the separator with the `separator` argument when uploading CSV files](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#csv-update-parameters).

```
&separator=%3B
```

(`%3B` is the URL encoded version of `;`)

You can give extra parameters to the `bin/post` commparameters by adding `-params "separator=%3B"`.

Comment: Now it's giving me **Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id** error but my uniqueKey is **id** field and it's in the csv file.

Comment: From the page linked above: **header**: Set to `true` if first line of input contains field names. Add that as well by adding &header=true to the params parameter.